# How to use rosserial_python?

Tags: serial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to use rosserial? How to use rosserial_python.

My task is writing a ROS node(python) to send command and receive status code from my mcu(had been programmed). through serial port(/dev/ttyUSB0, 9600)

I noticed that rosserial package is only working for "a connected rosserial-enabled device". Is that true?

How can I finish my task using the package"rosserial"? if can not, what is the most efficient way to achive that?

Thank you very much!!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225495/how-to-use-rosserial_python?/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[my blog](http://blog.csdn.net/sonictl/article/details/50623662) described several ways about ROS-Serial communication. I Pasted how to build a ros_node to do the "implement your own code in the node to translate the messages from the mcu into appropriate messages for ros topics, and subscribe to appropriate topics in ros and convert that data into appropriate messages for your mcu" as [nickw](http://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) said.

---

Originally posted by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) with karma: 287 on 2016-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosserial is used with mcus that have rosserial code running on them. As you already have a different protocol on your mcu (you describe it as programmed already, I am assuming that it is not running rosserial code) then you will need to implement your own code in the node to translate the messages from the mcu into appropriate messages for ros topics, and  subscribe to appropriate topics in ros and convert that data into appropriate messages for your mcu. These will need to be sent over serial, using something like pyserial

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-02-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fsteinhardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4889/fsteinhardt/) on 2016-02-01**:
or http://wiki.ros.org/serial for C++

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-02-02**:
Thank you very much! @nickw